# Problem with personalised Keyboard with UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, custom-keyboard

I'm trying to create a personalised keyboard to fill a `UITextField` from the value of the `UIPickerView` keyboard.

I've got created the keyboard but when I select one value in my keyboard nothing appears in the `UITextField`...

First I declare a lazy `UIPickerView`

```
lazy var DurationPicker: UIPickerView = {
        let DurationPicker = UIPickerView()
        DurationPicker.delegate = self
        DurationPicker.dataSource = self

        var flightTime: String = ""
        var row0: String = "0"
        var row1: String = "0"
        var row2: String = "0"
        var row4: String = "0"
        var row5: String = "0"

            row0 = myPickerRow1[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]

            row1 = myPickerRow2[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]

            row2 = myPickerRow3[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)]

            row4 = myPickerRow5[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 4)]

            row5 = myPickerRow6[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 5)]

        print("\(row0)\(row1)\(row2):\(row4)\(row5)")

        if row0 != "0"{
            flightTime = "\(row0)\(row1)\(row2):\(row4)\(row5)"
        }else if row0 == "0" && row1 != "0"  {
            flightTime = "\(row1)\(row2):\(row4)\(row5)"
        }else if row1 == "0" && row2 != "0"  {
            flightTime = "\(row2):\(row4)\(row5)"
        }
        print(flightTime)
        return DurationPicker
    }()
```

Secondly I call the right Keyboard in my `viewDidLoad` connected to the right `UITextfield`

```
flightTimeSe.inputView = DurationPicker
```

Finally I declare the `UIPickerView`

```
let myPickerRow1 = [String](arrayLiteral: "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
    let myPickerRow2 = [String](arrayLiteral: "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
    let myPickerRow3 = [String](arrayLiteral: "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
    let myPickerRow4 = [String](arrayLiteral: ":")
    let myPickerRow5 = [String](arrayLiteral: "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
    let myPickerRow6 = [String](arrayLiteral: "0", "5")

 func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if component == 0 {
            return myPickerRow1.count
        }else if component == 1{
            return myPickerRow2.count
        }else if component == 2{
            return myPickerRow3.count
        }else if component == 3{
            return myPickerRow4.count
        }else if component == 4{
            return myPickerRow5.count
        }
        return myPickerRow6.count
    }

    func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if component == 0 {
            return myPickerRow1[row]
        }else if component == 1{
            return myPickerRow2[row]
        }else if component == 2{
            return myPickerRow3[row]
        }else if component == 3{
            return myPickerRow4[row]
        }else if component == 4{
            return myPickerRow5[row]
        }
        return myPickerRow6[row]
    }

    func pickerView( pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        var flightTime: String = ""
        var row0: String = "0"
        var row1: String = "0"
        var row2: String = "0"
        var row4: String = "0"
        var row5: String = "0"

        if component == 0 {
            row0 = myPickerRow1[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        }else if component == 1{
            row1 = myPickerRow2[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
        }else if component == 2{
            row2 = myPickerRow3[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)]
        }else if component == 4{
            row4 = myPickerRow5[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 4)]
        }else if component == 5{
            row5 = myPickerRow6[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 5)]
        }
        print("\(row0)\(row1)\(row2):\(row4)\(row5)")
        if myPickerRow1[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] != "0"{
            flightTime = "\(myPickerRow1[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)])\(myPickerRow2[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)])\(myPickerRow3[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)]):\(myPickerRow5[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 4)])\(myPickerRow6[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 5)])"
        }else if myPickerRow1[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] == "0" && myPickerRow2[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)] != "0"  {
            flightTime = "\(myPickerRow2[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)])\(myPickerRow3[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)]):\(myPickerRow5[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 4)])\(myPickerRow6[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 5)])"
        }else if myPickerRow2[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)] == "0" && myPickerRow3[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)] != "0"  {
            flightTime = "\(myPickerRow3[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)]):\(myPickerRow5[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 4)])\(myPickerRow6[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 5)])"
        }
        flightTimeSe.text = "\(flightTime)"
        print(flightTime)
    }
```

Currently when I select the right TextField it show the picker view keyboard. I can select the my value in my picker but nothing go to my textfield ...

I didn't know where I make a mistake ...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does the console print the correct value?

Comment: @matt negative it print 000:00 ...

Comment: And is that correct? Also you are not answering my question. Your code has TWO print statements.

Comment: When the keyboard appears Yes but when I change the value no more print is done by the console ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Change

```
func pickerView( pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int
```

To

```
func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int
```

Second: you have this very dubious logic:

```
if myPickerRow1[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] != "0"{

}else if myPickerRow1[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] == "0" && myPickerRow2[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)] != "0"  {

}else if myPickerRow2[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)] == "0" && myPickerRow3[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)] != "0"  {

}
```

It is very likely that none of those is true, so you end up with an empty string being sent to your text field.

Comment: Wonderfull ! I don't really understand why it work but it works !!! thanks a lot !

Comment: How can I deal to have the same Picker keyboard in different textfield ? I know How to call the keyboard in different text field but not how to dispatch the value. Currently when I call the keyboard in an other TF I only could modify the first TF value ...

Comment: It is up to you to record what text field is being edited, so that you modify that one when the value changes.

Comment: I never do that before ... how can I did that ? Shall I need to put this instruction in the Lazy ?

Comment: Give the text fields a delegate. The delegate is told when the field starts editing. Now you know which field is being edited. If you need details, ask a new question!

Comment: I've been create a new question because I don't know how to fix it with delegate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55354059/fill-different-uitextfield-with-the-same-personalised-keyboard/55354224#55354224