# Fill different UITextField with the same personalised keyboard

Tags: swift, delegates, uitextfield

I've got a view where I've different `UITextfield`. To fil this TF I use a personalised `UIPickerview` as keyboard.

My problem is, when I select the First TF the keyboard open and I can select my value. The value go to this selected TF. Now when I select the second TF the keyboard appears but the value goes to the first TF ...

I don't know why this not works ...

In my `ViewDidLoad` T've got :

```
flightTimeSe.inputAccessoryView = Ttoolbar
flightTimeSe.delegate = self
flightTimeMe.inputView = DurationPicker
flightTimeMe.inputAccessoryView = Ttoolbar
flightTimeMe.delegate = self
flightTimeMp.inputView = DurationPicker
```

This assign the `UIPickerview`to the TF and Also my toolbar.

My `UIPickerview` is defined as follow :

```
lazy var DurationPicker: UIPickerView = {
        let DurationPicker = UIPickerView()
        DurationPicker.delegate = self
        DurationPicker.dataSource = self

        var flightTime: String = ""
        var row0: String = "0"
        var row1: String = "0"
        var row2: String = "0"
        var row4: String = "0"
        var row5: String = "0"

            row0 = myPickerRow1[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]

            row1 = myPickerRow2[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]

            row2 = myPickerRow3[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)]

            row4 = myPickerRow5[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 4)]

            row5 = myPickerRow6[DurationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 5)]

        //print("\(row0)\(row1)\(row2):\(row4)\(row5)")

        if row0 != "0"{
            flightTime = "\(row0)\(row1)\(row2):\(row4)\(row5)"
        }else if row0 == "0" && row1 != "0"  {
            flightTime = "\(row1)\(row2):\(row4)\(row5)"
        }else if row1 == "0" && row2 != "0"  {
            flightTime = "\(row2):\(row4)\(row5)"
        }else if row2 == "0" && row4 != "0"  {
            flightTime = "\(row2):\(row4)\(row5)"
        }else if row2 == "0" && row4 == "0" && row5 != "0" {
            flightTime = "\(row2):\(row4)\(row5)"
        }
        print(flightTime)
        return DurationPicker
    }()
```

I don't now how to deal with my delegate to fill the right TF...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Better approach is create a function which takes textfield and tag, creates UIPickerView object and set as input view of textfield, while creating you can assign tag to UIPickerView, in delegate you can read tag of date picker and update textfield accordingly.

Comment: Are you setting tags for each picker view?